# Messed up with /dev/tty* ownership

Tags: linux, arch-linux, chmod, chown, dev

I was flashing a Flipper Zero Wifi Dev Board and I needed to have /dev/ttyACM0 owned by dialout group...

The thing is now I have tried to revert the stuff, making a chown root:tty /dev/tty*, and chmod a+0666 permissions, and, well... It connects USB on readonly mode.

I can remount Pen Drives easily with a mount command and mode rw, but ironically, I cannot update my Flipper Board now, so I need help... Either making sure everything gets as it should be and making sure any device is connected automatically on rw mode.

I am using archlinux (btw)

I appreciate any help

---

OK, seems like whenever the OS is rebooted, the permissions fall back to normal. However, I still have that very same problem as before: Now, I have to remount any USB device so that they are accessed in rw mode.

So I need to know how to turn back that configuration to normal.

Answer (score 0):

Part of the conversation can be followed [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/765818/i-messed-dev-tty-ownership-and-permissions). To summarize, it seems that after an OS update everything has gone back to normal. So now, I am pending of checking the logs and see what has changed.

Thank you.